# ReST: POST: java.io.IOException: Unsupported Media Type

Tags: java, rest, post

I'm trying to make a POST call to a local ReST service that sends back a simple XML response.

I'm getting back this error:

```
java.io.IOException: Unsupported Media Type
    at com.eric.RawTestPOST.httpPost(RawTestPOST.java:42)
    at com.eric.RawTestPOST.main(RawTestPOST.java:66)
```

I'm following this example:[Link](http://rest.elkstein.org/2008/02/using-rest-in-java.html)

Here is my code:

```
public class RawTestPOST {

public static String httpPost(String urlStr, String method,
        String parameter, String parameterValue) throws Exception {
    URL url = new URL(urlStr);
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
    conn.setDoOutput(true);
    conn.setDoInput(true);
    conn.setUseCaches(false);
    conn.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
            "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    // Create the form content
    OutputStream out = conn.getOutputStream();
    Writer writer = new OutputStreamWriter(out, "UTF-8");
    /* for (int i = 0; i < string.length; i++) { */
    writer.write(method);
    writer.write("?");
    writer.write(parameter);
    writer.write("=");
    writer.write(URLEncoder.encode(parameterValue, "UTF-8"));
    writer.write("&");
    /* } */
    writer.close();
    out.close();

    if (conn.getResponseCode() != 200) {
        throw new IOException(conn.getResponseMessage());
    }

    // Buffer the result into a string
    BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn
            .getInputStream()));
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String line;
    while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
        sb.append(line);
    }
    rd.close();

    conn.disconnect();
    return sb.toString();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String url = "http://localhost:9082/ServicesWSRest/";
    String method = "getResponse";
    String parameter = "empID";
    String parameterValue = "954";
    try {
        System.out.println(RawTestPOST.httpPost(url, method, parameter,
                parameterValue));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

The parameters are not imprtant. The XML response just returns the parameters sent in.

I can get it to work with a GET request.

Let me know if y'all need anymore information.

Thanks,
E

Comment: This may be specific to the server you are connecting to, as it is the answer returned by the server, not by the Java networking code; the server can, for example, specify that it does not support POST requests for the particular resource that you are requesting. Can you provide more info about the server that you are connecting to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unsupported Media Type indicates that the media type of the representation you POSTed to the web service ('application/x-www-form-urlencoded') isn't one the web service supports.  I'd hazard a guess that the web service is expecting 'application/xml' representations.  It all depends on the web app you're talking to of course.

Comment: Cool. Let me figure out the return type. Thanks!