# Jersey post operation with data as query string in url throws http 415 jdev 11g and weblogic 10.3

Tags: java, jersey, weblogic

[Jersey POST Method is receiving null values as parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10357041/jersey-post-method-is-receiving-null-values-as-parameters/10361028#10361028)

I have followed similar approach as mention.My goal is to post operation on a resource for inserting into database. But server throws me unsupported media type 415 excption.I have war deployed on integrated weblogic.
jersey 1.1.5.
Client would send me url with data as query string

```
http://myurl:port/myapp/load/updateLoad?param1=value1&param2=value2
```

My resource is defined as :

```
@Resource
@Path("/load")
public class LocationUpdtService extends CoreService {

@POST
@Path("/updateLoad")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_XML)
public Integer updateLocationDataOnLoad(@QueryParam("ID")
    String id, @QueryParam("Latitude")
    double latitude, @QueryParam("Longitude") double longitude,
```

My web.xml is this

```
<?xml version = '1.0' encoding = 'windows-1252'?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee">
 <display-name>Highway Integration</display-name>
 <filter>
   <filter-name>JpsFilter</filter-name>
   <filter-class>oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsFil ter</filter-class>
   <init-param>
     <param-name>enable.anonymous</param-name>
     <param-value>true</param-value>
   </init-param>
 </filter>
 <filter-mapping>
   <filter-name>JpsFilter</filter-name>
   <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
   <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
   <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
   <dispatcher>INCLUDE</dispatcher>
 </filter-mapping>
 <servlet>
   <display-name>App Point Rest Servlet</display-na me>
   <servlet-name>App Point Rest Servlet</servlet-na me>
   <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.serv let.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
   <init-param>
       <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.feature.Tr ace</param-name>
       <param-value>true</param-value>
   </init-param>
 <!--  <init-param>
     <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.pac kages</param-name>
     <param-value>com.mygrp.myapp.rest</param-value >
   </init-param>
   -->
   <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
 </servlet>
 <servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>App Rest Servlet</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
 <session-config>
   <session-timeout>15</session-timeout>
 </session-config>
</web-app>
```

Also I tried using SOAPUI as well as HttpAnalyser as well java client same resp 415.

Explicityly setting content typle Application_url_form_encoded

Comment: You probably still need to change your content type. Here is an example similar to the problem you're seeing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13246529/http-415-while-sending-json-object-using-post

Comment: what do I set mediaType to as it is Post with data as part of url and post takes either Application_Form_UrlEncoded or Multiform Part?? I tried plain text, text/xml or not annotation. Nothing works.

Comment: Try just xml? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8750961/rest-post-java-io-ioexception-unsupported-media-type